# Rails simple_form grouped_select strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Strange thing happened to me recently.

I have two models:

```
class Direction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specializations, dependent: :destroy
end

and

class Specialization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :direction
end
```

They both have a field called `title`.

I've made a form (it is not tied to any model) with a grouped select:

```
= simple_form_for :some_name do |f|
  = f.input :specialization_id, collection: Direction.all,
            as: :grouped_select,
            group_method: :specializations
```

And everything is just fine on my local machine. My select looks like this:

```
Direction1 title
  Specialization1 title
  Specialization2 title
  ...
Direction2 title
  Specialization3 title
  Specialization4 title
  ...
...
```

When I deployed it to staging server there was a little surprise. My select output has become something like this:

```
#<Direction:0xb02fb60>
  #<Specialization:0xaa5fb10>
  ...
#<Direction:0x991cf90>
  #<Specialization:0xb02f868>
  ...
```

It looks like it's calling `:to_s` as a label method (and value method too) instead of `:title`.

The problem is fixed by explicitly specifying those methods:

```
= simple_form_for :some_name do |f|
  = f.input :specialization_id, collection: Direction.all,
            as: :grouped_select,
            group_method: :specializations,
            group_label_method: :title,
            label_method: :title,
            value_method: :id
```

But I want to know why did it happen? I don't like this kind of surprises. : )

Some details:

- Local machine is running MacOS Lion
- Staging server is on Debian Squeeze
- Ruby version is the same (1.9.3p194 via rvm)
- Rails version: 3.2.3
- Deploying with Capistrano

I also tried to reproduce it locally on a virtual Debian machine for debugging purposes. But I had no success.

Can somebody tell me what's happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same behavior only in production mode.

```
= f.input(:city_id, label: 'Ciudad', :collection => Country.order(:name), :as =>     :grouped_select, :group_method => :cities, :group_label_method => :name, :label_method => :name, promt: "Por favor seleccione una ciudad", :include_blank => true, :input_html => { class: 'span4'} )
```

I expect to get the city id instead returns

```
"#<City:0x007f943d5a2de0>"
```

**UPDATE**

I added the simple_form propety **value_method: :id** and works fine to me.

```
= f.input(:city_id, label: 'Ciudad', :collection => Country.order(:name), :as =>     :grouped_select, :group_method => :cities, :group_label_method => :name, :label_method => :name, promt: "Por favor seleccione una ciudad", value_method: :id, :include_blank => true, :input_html => { class: 'span4'} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with f.association

for example:

```
 = f.association :direction
```

You can also call label_method for define label in option

Comment: The form is not tied to any model. Please, read question more carefully. :) Btw, the main question is why did it happen only on the staging server..